# Hopf invariant and homotopy groups of spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

I am trying to understand how to use Hopf invariant, to calculate $\pi_{4n-1}(S^{2n})$.

I've started with defining a new space $X$ adjoining $D^{4n}$ to $S^{2n}$ via a map $\phi\in\pi_{4n-1}(S^{2n}) $. I can see that this new space has $C_n(X)$ zero when $n$ is not 0, 2n, 4n.

Now I need to calculate $H^{4n}$, $H^{2n}$. For this do I need to use some kind of exact sequence of cohomology groups?

Then I need to show that generators of these groups are one is multiple of the other using cup product.

Lastly, I need to show this multiple element, called Hopf invariant, only depends on homotopy class of $\phi$.

This theorems are stated in algebraic topology books however I am struggling to understand mid-steps. Any help, hint or idea will be appreciated.

Comment: There cannot be any differentials in the cellular complex $C _n(X)$ as no 2 consecutive groups are non-zero. So that gives you $H^{2n} \cong H^{4n} \cong \mathbb{Z}$. And cohomology rings being homotopy invariant only depend on the homotopy type of the attaching maps.